# Smooth function with non-zero derivative having bounded number of zeros in a compact interval?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Suppose $f^{(n)}(a) \neq 0$ for some $n \geq 2$. 
I was wondering is it possible to prove that there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that 
$f$ only has finitely many zeros in the interval $[a-\epsilon, a+ \epsilon]$? 
If $n=1$ this is clear.

The function given in the answer in [Smooth function with all derivatives zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680554/smooth-function-with-all-derivatives-zero) is an example of a non-constant smooth function which has infinitely many zeros 
in $[0-\epsilon, 0 + \epsilon]$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. But this example satisfies $f^{(n)}(a) = 0$ for all $n$. I was wondering if we can make the number of zeros to be finite with some kind of non-zero derivative assumption. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this follows the usual way. There is some minimal $k$ so that $f^{(k)}(a)\ne 0$, then there is by the continuity of that derivative some $ϵ>0$ so that $|f^{(k+1)}(x)(x-a)|<\frac12|f^{(k)}(a)|$ for $x\in(a−ϵ,a+ϵ)$. From that it follows that $f$ is close enough to its most trivial non-trivial Taylor polynomial (monomial) to conclude that there are no roots in that interval for $k=0$ or a $k$-fold root at $x=a$ for $k>0$ and no other roots.

It is perhaps easier to just divide out the linear factors, $f(x)=(x-a)^kg(x)$ with $g(a)=\frac1{k!}f^{(k)}(a)$, so that roots of $f$ other than $a$ are also roots of $g$. Then argue by the continuity of $g$ and $g(a)\ne 0$ that $a$ is an isolated root (or that there are no roots at all close to $a$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do you deduce from $|g^{(k)}(x)|>\frac12|g^{(k)}(a)|$ for $x\in(a−ϵ,a+ϵ)$ that there are no zeros in this interval? I am not quite seeing this...

Comment: Perhaps that is not sufficient. The general idea is to compare $f(x)$ to its simplest non-trivial Taylor polynomial $p_k(x)=\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k$. Then the logical condition is that the next term be small enough so that $|f(x)|\ge|p_k(x)|-|f(x)-p_k(x)|>0$. I'll change that.

Comment: I see, thank you!